# TextInputLayout hides automatically for some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I've added 7+ TextInpuLayout with parent ScrollView and TextInputLayout hides after showing only first one for some devices and for some devices it's working very good.
here is two screenshots for better understanding

working good for few devices
[image]

[image: but hides automatically like this]

but hides automatically like this

i'm using `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`
 for design library.

and here is the layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="clockworktt.gaby.com.GuestProfileActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/guest_profile_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/guest_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/guest_profile_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Guest Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/almostWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_name_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_salutation_input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Salutation"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_occupation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    >

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Occupation"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/profile_company"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Company"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Phone"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_expected_numbers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Expected Numbers"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:hint="Notes"
                    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/profile_update_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Update"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/almostWhite"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

please someone help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to set **layout_height** attribute of TextInputLayout to **wrap_content**.